# How to clear text content in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

After getting the text in the RichTextBox I want to clear the text. How can I do that?

```
TextRange txt = new TextRange(richtxtSNotice.Document.ContentStart, richtxtSNotice.Document.ContentEnd);
MessageBox.Show(txt.Text);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to create a `TextRange` with `RichBoxText` content, then set `Text` to empty string:

```
TextRange txt = new TextRange(richtxtSNotice.Document.ContentStart, richtxtSNotice.Document.ContentEnd);
txt.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 108):

Use the following:

```
_richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();
```

Comment: Don't get me started...  Yup, lots of hidden stuff.  However, it's much better than the earlier days of Win32 and WinForms.  You pretty much had to know good voodoo to figure those 'hidden' things out.  It's getting better and better.  I've LOVED WPF since it came out.  Though it does have a couple hiccups, it's SO much easier than the way we used to have to do things in a desktop UI.  Happy times all around.  That's what I call job security...

Answer (score 14):

This is a simple way of doing it.

```
        public void Clear()
        {
            richTextBox1.SelectAll();

            richTextBox1.Selection.Text = "";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble clearing the rich text box when I had some InlineUIContainer elements, for example buttons, in the rich text box. In this case, I got an exception for

```
myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear ();
```

I could work around this with

```
myRichTextBox.Document = new System.Windows.Documents.FlowDocument ();
```

Of course, this works whether we have InlineUIContainer elements in it or not.

Comment: I was getting `NullReferenceException`s in my `myRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear()` calls too, randomly (some times they were thrown, sometimes not), and I also had `InlineUIContainer` elements.

Your solution of redefining the whole Document worked!

Answer (score -3):

I found that clearing the richTextBox didn't always remove all of the text from the richTextBox using richTextBox.Text = ""; or richTextBox.Clear();  Only the first few lines were cleared.

To fix this issue, I included the Update() function call  solved this issue.

```
richTextBox.Clear();
```

followed by

```
richTextBox.Update();
```

to reliably clear the richTextBox.

Answer (score -3):

To clear all content of richtext box you can use the following code

```
richTextBox1->SelectAll();
richTextBox1->Clear();
```

Comment: Is `->` valid syntax for C#? Or is this code snippet from another programming language?

Comment: This won't compile

Comment: valid for c++ WFA

Answer (score -14):

easiest way I know how is to put

```
       (your richTextbox name).text = "";
```

that tells it to replace anything in the textbox field with blank code. I'm sure there are other ways to do it too though.