# Cant clear textbox and richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, richtextbox

I have a WPF project with a navigation window and a few pages. On one page I have a textbox and two richtextboxes. With a click on a button I want to clear the textbox and the two richtextboxes with the following code:

```
private void resetGUI()
{
    txtIndex.Clear();
    richEinzelTxtBemerkung.Document.Blocks.Clear();
    richTxtBemerkung.Document.Blocks.Clear();
    checkHauptzeichnung.IsChecked = false;
}
```

But it doesnt work. It seems that the clear method delete the value of the fields internal but in the GUI the value stays.

So what do you think might cause this problem?

Comment: Try `txtIndex.Text="";` and for richtextbox, try this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805134/how-to-clear-text-content-in-richtextbox

Comment: code working fine

Comment: But i want to delete the value out of the GUI, too. It clears the value out of the Boxes internal but the GUI shows the old values that dont exist anymore. I tried all the solutions of the link.

Comment: the posted code is not the problem. Might it be that you fill the textboxes again after `resetGUI` somewhere in another method?

Comment: @Only3lue that code seems find maybe there's an event that fill your textbox try hitting break point after `txtIndex.Clear();` see if your textbox is really being clear

Comment: Oh yes. I thougt again of it and i found my mistake. It was a mistake with a wrong index count.

Comment: @NewbeeDev The GUI will be updated when you return from the break-point-debugging. It won't be of much help unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i found my mistake. I fill the Boxes again after clearing them. J found a mistake with a index count.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
txtIndex.Text = String.Empty;
```

or

```
txtIndex.Text = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to clear Text of Rich Textbox.

1)  `richTextbox.Text="";`

2) `richTextbox.Text=string.Empty;`

3) Declare one global variable like:

string emptyString="";

and assign to every taxtbox, richtextbox and variable which you want to clear

a)`richTextbox.Text=emptyString;`
 b)`nameTextbox.Text=emptyString;`
 c)`name=emptyString;`

Thanks.