# Clear RichTextBox Before Writing New Text

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I'm using Visual Studio, WPF, C#, XAML.

I have a RichTextBox that C# writes text to on button press.

Each time the button is pressed it *appends* the new text to the RichTextBox, leaving the old text.

I need it to clear the old text before writing the new, so it doesn't stack up.

**XAML**

```
<RichTextBox Name="richTextBox1" IsUndoEnabled="False" />
```

**C#**

Clear

```
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
```

---

```
public static System.Windows.Media.Brush White = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFFFFF"));
public static Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();

// Button
private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

    //Clear() put here, does nothing


    // New Document
    richTextBox1.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);


    //Clear() put here works but wont write new text, stays blank


    //begin writing
    richTextBox1.BeginChange();

        //Clear() put here works but wont write new text, stays blank

        //write text
        paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello, World.") { Foreground = White });

    //end writing
    richTextBox1.EndChange();


    richTextBox1.UpdateLayout(); //does nothing
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to clear the text of the RichTextBox:

1. Use the clear method:

   ```
   richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
   ```

   As I mentioned, this way doesn't work for you
2. Select all of your RichTextBox and set the Text to "":

   ```
   richTextBox1.SelectAll();
   richTextBox1.Selection.Text = "";
   ```

   Do this, before you start to change.
3. Use TextRange, to get the text and clear it with "":

   ```
   TextRange txt = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
   txt.Text="";
   ```

My answer is a conclusion from this question: [how to clear text content in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805134/how-to-clear-text-content-in-richtextbox)

---

**Update**: You can try the following:

1. Create an object from FlowDocument:

   ```
   FlowDocument ObjFdoc = new FlowDocument();
   ```
2. Create a paragraph:

   ```
   Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
   paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hello, World.") { Foreground = White });
   ```
3. Add the paragraph to the FlowDocument:

   ```
   ObjFdoc.Blocks.Add(ObjPara1);
   ```
4. Set the RichtTextBox.Document:

   ```
   richTextBox1.Document=ObjFdoc;
   ```

Every time you call your method, it will be generate a new flowdocument and gc deletes the old flowdocuments for you.

Comment: It clears, but it won't write the new text. It stays cleared.

Comment: What if you use "richTextBox1.UpdateLayout();" before "BeginChange"?

Comment: I put the SelectAll() clear at the top and added a second "richTextBox1.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);" before it. I think it's working, I'm going to test it for a while and I'll accept your answer, the SelectAll() worked where the Blocks.Clear() doesn't.

Comment: @MattMcManis I have update my answer. Perhaps, I will help you more than the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I need 50 reputation to comment...

Is there a particular reason for you to assign a new `FlowDocument` to the `RichTextBox` every time the button is pressed?

You're clearing the documents content in the `Clear()` method and than attach a new `FlowDocument` object with the entire paragraph to the `RichTextBox`, thus appending the new text to the same paragraph.

Try removing the `richTextBox1.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);` line.

Comment: The program is a bit more complicated. The button actually opens a new window with a RichTextBox and runs a Write() method at the same time. It doesn't seem to work without a new FlowDocument. But thanks for explaining why its appending.

Answer (score 0):

Because the text was added in a paragraph (Block) contained in your FlowDocument( 
`richtextBox1.Document`) it has to be cleared using this code:

```cs
 paragraph.Inlines.Clear();
```

Explanation: 
The issue here is that you are clearing all blocks from your FlowDocument, including your single `paragraph` so next time you want to append text in that paragraph it won't work, of course, the text is added to the paragraph referenced by `paragraph` but it is not part of the document any more.

Here are some unit Tests

```cs
 [Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
    public class Tests
    {
        public static System.Windows.Media.Brush White = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FFFFFF"));
        protected Paragraph paragraph;
        protected RichTextBox richTextBox1;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            richTextBox1 = new RichTextBox();
            paragraph = new Paragraph();
            richTextBox1.Document = new FlowDocument(paragraph);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This reproduce the issue
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void Adding_Text_After_Blocks_Clear_Should_Not_Work_The_issue()
        {
            paragraph.AddText("Hello, World!");

            string content1 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World!", content1);

            richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            string content2 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("", content2);

            paragraph.AddText("Howdy!");

            string content3 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            //are not equal
            Assert.AreNotEqual("Howdy!", content3);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Adding_TextAfter_Paragraph_Clear_Should_Work_Solution()
        {
            paragraph.AddText("Hello, World!");

            string content1 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World!", content1);

            paragraph.Inlines.Clear();

            string content2 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("", content2);

            paragraph.AddText("Howdy!");

            string content3 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("Howdy!", content3);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Keep in mind tha if the  RichTextBox is not readonly, deleting text with CTRL-A + DELETE 
        /// Causes the same issues.
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void Clearing_Blocks_Should_Remove_All_Paragraphs_The_Cause_of_issue()
        {
            paragraph.AddText("Hello, World!");

            string content1 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World!", content1);

            var blocksBefore = richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.ToArray();

            Assert.IsTrue(ReferenceEquals(paragraph, blocksBefore[0]));

            richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            var blocksAfter = richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.ToArray();

            Assert.AreEqual(0, blocksAfter.Length);
        }


        [Test]
        public void Added_New_Text_after_Blocks_Clear_Should_Work()
        {
            paragraph.AddText("Hello, World!");

            string content1 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World!", content1);

            richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            string content2 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("", content2);

            var p = new Paragraph();

            p.AddText("Howdy!");

            //Add this to the blocks collection!!!!
            richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(p);

            string content3 = richTextBox1.GetText();

            Assert.AreEqual("Howdy!", content3);
        }
    }

    public static class RTBExtentions
    {
        public static string GetText(this RichTextBox rtb)
        {
            return new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd).Text.TrimEnd();
        }
        public static void AddText(this Paragraph paragraph, string textToAdd, Brush foregroundColor = default(Brush))
        {
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(textToAdd) { Foreground = foregroundColor });
        }

        public static Block[] ToArray(this BlockCollection blocks)
        {
            List<Block> elements = new List<Block>();

            foreach (var item in blocks)  {  elements.Add(item);  }

            return elements.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I 'approving' your answer but, for future reference, you should try to add a bit more 'explanation', rather than just posting very terse answers.

Comment: Thank's! I'll explain this answer asap