# Error when displaying data in RichTextBox after clearing it

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox on my GUI and I Have two buttons, one to display data and one to clear data. On button DISPLAY, I use this routine to display some data into the RichTextBox:

```
Block firstBlock = richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.FirstOrDefault();
richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.InsertBefore(firstBlock, new Paragraph(new Run("MyFirstLine= " + MyVariable + "\n" )));

string message;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    message = "";
    message += "Line:" + (i + 1).ToString() + "\n";
    richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.InsertBefore(firstBlock, new Paragraph(new Run(message)));
}
```

And on CLEAR click, I do [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805134/how-to-clear-text-content-in-richtextbox):

```
richTextBox_Console.SelectAll();
richTextBox_Console.Selection.Text = "";
```

Now when I click the DISPLAY button again, and on line:

```
richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.InsertBefore(firstBlock, new Paragraph(new Run("MyFirstLine= " + MyVariable + "\n" )));
```

`firstBlock` is `null` so the line throws this error:

> value can not be null. Parameter name: nextSibling

Any idea what is going on? It works fine to display data the first time then never works.

I also tried doing `richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.Clear();` to clear but I get the same error still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the event handler for the delete button like this:

```
richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.Clear();
richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before your code

```
if(!richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.Any())richTextBox_Console.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph());
```

It will check if there are any blocks in your text, and if no - it will add a paragraph for you.

Also, you better to change FirstOrDefault() to First(), in this case next time you will know the problem is that you have no paragraphs/sections